# Passing value to method in object in service and then pass response to other method in same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, parameter-passing

So as title says I'm passing a value from view through controller to method in myService which fire other method in same object.

So the way of this variable is

view -> controller -> service -> method2 -> method1

HTML

```
<select id="final_price_currency"
    ng-model="selectedCurrency"
    ng-change="currencySelect.fireCurrencyChanger()">
        <option ng-repeat="n in currencySelect.availableOptions" value="{{n.name}}">{{n.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.currencySelect = {
    availableOptions: [
        {name: 'USD'},
        {name: 'EUR'},
        {name: 'GBP'},
        {name: 'CHF'},
        {name: 'PLN'}
    ],
    fireCurrencyChanger: function() {
        var priceField = $scope.price;
        var selectedCurrency = $scope.selectedCurrency;
        currencyConverterService.currencyConverter.convertMoney(selectedCurrency,priceField);
    }
}
```

Method2 in service (just the beginning):

```
// parameters are also used in convertMoney
convertMoney: function(selectedCurrency,priceField) {
    this.getRatio(selectedCurrency);
```

Method1 in service(just the beginning aswell):

```
getRatio: function(selectedCurrency) {
    var selectedCurrency = this.selectedCurrency ;
    $http({
        url: 'http://api.fixer.io/latest?base='+selectedCurrency +'&symbols=PLN,CHF,EUR,USD,GBP',
        method: 'GET'
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        var currentCurrency = {
            toPLN:  response.data.rates.PLN,
            toCHF:  response.data.rates.CHF,
            toEUR:  response.data.rates.EUR,
            toUSD:  response.data.rates.USD,
            toGBP:  response.data.rates.GBP
        }
```

And as you see on success call of getting current currency I create another object which stores exchange rate for future calculations in **Method2**.

Questions:

- how can I pass this object which is created on success call in Method1 to Method2?
- is my logic of doing this currency changer on front-end make any sense?
- did I've done some mistakes already?

Note:

I know it's not safety at all. It is only for frontend use.

Comment: I think in your method 1 var selectedCurrency = this.selectedCurrency ; should be var selectedCurrency = selectedCurrency ;